# Passenger and Apache: X-died: bad chunck size

Tags: apache, passenger

I am upgrading an old Rails application to the most recent versions of Ruby, Rails, Authlogic, Passenger etc. The new version works OK with WEBrick, but I cannot get it to work with Apache2.2 and Passenger 3.0.7 (the old one worked nicely). The problem is that the requests return a bad chunk size header and no content:

GET http://www.xxx.xxx:6090/user_sessions/new returns:

Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

Connection: close

Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 20:15:17 GMT

ETag: "3fca75eeb48caf4fe548695a588b916d"

Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.7

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Client-Aborted: die

Client-Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 20:15:17 GMT

Client-Peer: xxx.xxx.14.54:6090

Client-Response-Num: 1

Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Set-Cookie:

_postliste_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlNjQ3MzJmMWE3NDY3ZGQ2YWYwZWEzMjBmMjliYzk5NDZJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFQLy94REd2MGxqMFNlYm1HUWNvOGh5THE4NU5RY2xXODVEWFVLU2EvMUxvPQY7AEY%3D--a1dc7975c23d0139ab92a20a88395ea3c4bc7304; path=/; HttpOnly

Status: 200

X-Died: Bad chunk-size in HTTP response: %lx at /local/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 484.

X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7

X-Runtime: 0.035096

X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1

I fail to see the way out and would greatly appreciate suggestions to solve the problem.

Regards

### Per

Solved:

Installed Apache 2.2.19 from scratch with fresh APU and APR 
./configure --prefix=/site/opt/apache-test --with-included-apr

Installed Passenger 3.0.8 and took care to use new APU and APR

Don't know if the APU/APR-stuff was significant, but the reinstallation solved the problem of bad 
chunking of the http-messages.

Per